# Nest JS swagger API response body from third party package

Tags: nestjs, openapi, nestjs-swagger

I am writing a REST API swagger in Nest JS.

My code snippet looks like this:

```js
  @Get()
  @ApiOperation({
    summary: `Something`,
    description: `Something`,
  })
  @ApiOkResponse({
    description: 'The resources were returned successfully',
    type: VpcV1,
    isArray: true
  })
  @ApiForbiddenResponse({ description: 'Unauthorized Request' })
  list() {
    return this.service.list();
  }
```

As you can see the the `this.service.list()` is returning ab object of type `VpcV1`.

I have added it as type in the `@ApiOkResponse()`.

But as the `VpcV1` is from third party package which I do not have any control, it's *not a DTO*.
In such a case how can I see the API response object such that when user will see the swagger, they can be able to see the Response Schema properly?